# docx module import error in terminal in python3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to use docx module in my program. I imported it by doing

```
pip install --user python-docx
```

Everything should work fine but when I import it in the interactive shell or try to run any code containing this module i get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'
```

I've seen many questions here about this but none of the answers helped me. I also should point out that I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running this:

```
pip install --upgrade dbus-python
```

Comment: while installing it this error showed up: `error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dbus-python

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.`